# Which sentence is most suitable in the context of history?

Tags: phrase-requests, syntactic-analysis, sentence-patterns

1. The day of sorrow becomes the day of happiness.
2. The day of sorrow changes into the day of happiness.
3. The day of sorrow turns into the most peaceful day.

Detail context:
The day when one country dropped bombs on the city of another country is now remembered and observed as thanks giving day. I wish to stress the irony of such a thing.

Please suggest more suitable sentences.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use a paragraph, rather than a mere sentence, to convey your meaning.

Short, punchy statements are powerful, but only if they are adequate to the job.  You have a complex proposition, and if your audience could easily grasp the irony, they'd have done it long ago, and there'd be no point for you to make.

Give a city a bombing, and you have a tragedy for a generation. Teach a city about a bombing, and the thanksgiving is ironical for centuries.

Comment: It seems like this is just intended as a pithy slogan or introduction, not the entire treatise. Would you criticize _Give me liberty, or give me death_ because Patrick Henry didn't go into enough detail?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest:

```
The day of sorrow has become a day of happiness.
```

*has become* expresses the fact that the sorrow was in the past, there was an ongoing, perhaps gradual, transition, and we now have happiness.